in ggplot2 the appropriate legend modifications are not applied
In the following code is not represented in the plot:
`theme(legend.position = "right",
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "darkgrey"),
    legend.box.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
    legend.text.align = 0)`

It ran previously but stopped doing so after readjusting positions.
After trying multiple variations, it didn't work.
This is the legend generated with the following code (https://i.sstatic.net/ZOdcKXmS.png).
`| indication| indication.pseudo.zscore | tissue |
| ---------- | ------------------------ |----------|
| 'key1'   |           2.6              |  "All/AD"|
| 'key2'   |            1.8             |  "All/AD"|`

    `ad.p2 <- ggplot(data = df[indication %in% c("key1", "key2"),],
    aes(x = tissue,
    y = indication.pseudo.zscore,
    color = indication
    ),
    )+
    geom_point(
    shape = 18,
    alpha = 0.8, # transparency c(0,1)
    size = 4,
    stroke = 1
    )+
    theme(legend.position = "right",
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "darkgrey"),
    legend.box.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
    legend.text.align = 0)+
    guides(color = guide_legend(title = "title",
    ncol = 1,
    byrow = T,
    keywidth = 0.25,
    keyheight = 0.25,
    default.unit = "inch"))+
    scale_color_manual(
    labels = c("Alzheimer's Disease", "Senile Dementia"),
    values = c("turquoise1", "sienna1"))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
    theme_bw()+
    coord_flip()``


I tried the code described, and the desired plot was not generated.
p.s. I don't know how to import a table, feel free to advise.

Welcome to SO! The issue is that all modificatiopns you apply via theme() get overridden by theme_bw(). Move the respective code after theme_bw(), i.e. do ... + theme_bw() + theme(...) + .... For future questions see How to make a great reproducible example for some options to share your data.

If you do ggplot() + theme(.....) + theme_bw(), then theme_bw() will override all the things you set in theme(). Instead, do ggplot() + theme_bw() + theme(....).
